# Using re to split a string by byte size

Tags: python, regex, string, file, python-re

I have a file, `file.txt`, and I want to create new files such that all the files are less than 500 bytes in size. So say that `file.txt` is 1124 bytes in size, I would split it into 3 files `file-1.txt`, `file-2.txt`, and `file-3.txt` such that all those files would be less than 500 bytes. Also, I don't want to split in the middle of a word, but splitting a paragraph or sentence is fine.

Is there any way this can be done with `re` in python3?
I'm assuming each character is one byte so I've tried concatenating the contents of the file into one string and used patterns like these but none have worked with my intended results.

`re.compile('\s{,1}.{1,498}\s{1}')`

`re.compile('^\s.{1,498}\s$')`

Comment: “each character is one byte” is true only if _all_ characters are ASCII. E.g., the quotes in the previous sentence are not.

Comment: ... unless you write the files a in single-byte encoding like Windows codepage 1252 (similar to ISO-8859-1), in which case the “” quotes are OK, but many other characters aren't (like, e.g., the n-dash –), and anyway it's generally not recommended.

Comment: Why are you attempting this with a regex? Solving this with a regex is more annoying if anything. It's fairly straightforward to just open the file, and write to new files stopping when you hit the size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```py
import re

def splitter(text):
    tb = text.encode('utf-8')
    if len(tb) < 500:
        return [text]
    else:
        rgx = re.compile(b"[\s\S]*\W")
        m = rgx.match(tb[:499])
        return [tb[:len(m[0])].decode('utf-8')] + splitter(tb[len(m[0]):].decode('utf-8'))

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    chunks = splitter(f.read())
    for i in range(len(chunks)):
        with open(f"file-{i + 1}.txt", "w") as of:
            of.write(chunks[i])
```